# Filter/search a QFileSystemModel in a QListFiew (QSortFilterProxyModel maybe)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

What I am trying to do is Filter/Search a QListView that uses a QFileSystemModel to populate it: This is some of the window I have now using a test/dummy folder I made

[image]

(I am working on making a bulk file 'renamer', just the project I decided to learn as i go with)

I want to be able to search/filter the list view by typing something into the 'getOut' line edit. Something like this is my goal(which is from a old random youtube video **but it's using a QListWidget**

[image]

I read that a QSortFilterProxyModel is probably what I want to use but when I set the list views "setRootIndex" using a proxy - it throws an error.

`TypeError: index(self, int, int, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'`

**So my questions come down to this:**

1. Is it even possible to filter a QListView Like what I am going for above in the gif?
2. Is the QFileSystemModel able to be filtered/searched like that?
3. Is QSortFilterProxyModel the right tool for the job if the 2 above are ok?
4. Should I use a different model or make one (i think you can) that is more basic and open to filtering?

I can kind of do what I am trying for by using just the QFileSystemModel's "setNameFilters" and "setNameFilterDisables(False)" but I have to do it in such a weird way which you can see below.

```
def listPopulate(self):
    print('\ninside the listPopulate method now')
    getOut = self.getOutInputBox.text()
    gList = []
    gList.insert(0, getOut)
    if self.homes:
        if os.path.exists(self.homes):
            listModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
            listModel.setFilter(QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllEntries | QDir.Dirs | QDir.Files)
            listModel.setRootPath(self.homes)

            # proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
            # proxyModel.setSourceModel(listModel)

            self.mainListView.setModel(listModel)
            self.mainListView.setRootIndex(listModel.index(self.homes))
            if not getOut:
                print('\ngetOut empty')
            else:
                print(getOut)
                listModel.setNameFilters(gList)
                listModel.setNameFilterDisables(False)
```

_All the "gList" stuff is because 'setNameFilters' only takes in a list (I assume this is usually used to filter for file extensions) so I take the getOut Filter and throw it in a list. and I CAN get it to filter somewhat how I want but I have to type things like "*q*" to get filter to things with 'Q' in them. And 'self.homes' is just my path/dir that gets chosen by the user.

Comment: Why is it something intimidating? What can happen to you ?, How much bad you can receive are some virtual downvotes, or that your question is closed :-). And if I already point out the bad: what good things can happen? receive feedback, receive answers to your question, etc. So if it was your I would risk it since I have more to gain than lose. On the other hand, your question is interesting but it could be improved if you read [ask] and review the [tour].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76641777/qlistview-search-with-qtcore-qsortfilterproxymodel-doesnt-work-in-some-cases/76658523#76658523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your questions are answered if the QFileSystemModel filtering is correctly implemented using QSortFilterProxyModel.

The following solution is only possible for Qt>=5.10 since in that version we added the `recursiveFilteringEnabled` property that allows to do a recursive filtering in the tree models as in this case.

On the other hand you indicate that you had problems when you wanted to use QSortFilterProxyModel, before pointing out what was the problem you must understand that the view does not know and does not interest you if you know the model is a proxy or not, just wait for a model and a QModelIndex as rootIndex that belongs to that model. In your case, you must convert the index of the QFileSystemModel to that of the QSortFilterProxyModel using the `mapFromSource()` method.

And finally it seems that there is a bug because when the data is filtered and it gets empty then the rootIndex is changed internally so it has to be re-established as I did in my answer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(textChanged=self.on_textChanged)
        self.lv = QtWidgets.QListView()

        self._dirpath = QtCore.QDir.homePath()

        self.file_model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.file_model.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
        self.file_model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot 
            | QtCore.QDir.AllEntries 
            | QtCore.QDir.Dirs 
            | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(
            recursiveFilteringEnabled=True,
            filterRole=QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.file_model)
        self.lv.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        self.adjust_root_index()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(le)
        lay.addWidget(self.lv)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_textChanged(self, text):
        self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard("*{}*".format(text))
        self.adjust_root_index()

    def adjust_root_index(self):
        root_index = self.file_model.index(self._dirpath)
        proxy_index = self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(root_index)
        self.lv.setRootIndex(proxy_index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```